# Possible serial noise or corruption error when trying to upload code to ESP32 wroom32U custom board

Tags: arduino, pcb-design, esp32

When I try to upload any simple code, I get this corruption error, I have removed the IO12 as recommended, changed the baud rate, added 1 uF between enable pin and GND, tried both manual and auto upload methods, changed the pic, changed the cables and I still have nothing. Though it worked for 3-4 times and then stopped.

```
    Le croquis utilise 264133 octets (8%) de l'espace de stockage de programmes. Le maximum est de 3145728 octets.
Les variables globales utilisent 21408 octets (6%) de mémoire dynamique, ce qui laisse 306272 octets pour les variables locales. Le maximum est de 327680 octets.
esptool.py v4.5.1
Serial port COM7
Connecting....
Chip is ESP32-D0WD-V3 (revision v3.1)
Features: WiFi, BT, Dual Core, 240MHz, VRef calibration in efuse, Coding Scheme None
Crystal is 40MHz
MAC: 64:b7:08:4a:95:70
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Configuring flash size...
Flash will be erased from 0x00001000 to 0x00005fff...
Flash will be erased from 0x00008000 to 0x00008fff...
Flash will be erased from 0x0000e000 to 0x0000ffff...
Flash will be erased from 0x00010000 to 0x00050fff...
Compressed 17536 bytes to 12202...
Writing at 0x00001000... (100 %)

A fatal error occurred: Invalid head of packet (0x65): Possible serial noise or corruption.
```

I'm using Windows 10 operating system, and Arduino IDE 2.2.1 software.

Here's the schematics I used. I used verbose in core debug level and got the following:

```
rst:0x1 (POWERON_RESET),boot:0x3 (DOWNLOAD_BOOT(UART0/UART1/SDIO_REI_REO_V2))
waiting for download
```

[image]

[image]

I fixed the problem by using 3V3 power level on both the FTDI chip and ESP32, it's uploading perfectly but it keeps rebooting, here's serial monitor output:

```
abort() was called at PC 0x400d890d on core 0


Backtrace: 0x40083349:0x3ffbe9cc |<-CORRUPTED




ELF file SHA256: e7e23dd0276ce281

Rebooting...
ets Jul 29 2019 12:21:46

rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:2
load:0x3fff0030,len:1184
load:0x40078000,len:13232
load:0x40080400,len:3028
entry 0x400805e4
```

Comment: @Justme i just noticed that my RX and TX aren't the same length thus the pair is not diffrential , could it be the source of the problem ?

Comment: @walidBmd No it can't be the problem because RX and TX are not a differential pair. Also, having same length still does not make a differential pair. Upload the schematics.

Answer (score 1):

You are connecting USB UART with 5V IO to a MCU with 3.3V IO. That will genrally be a problem which may cause the communication problem.

The MCU may fail because of this overvoltage or the MCU may be damaged. Or the FTDI may have problems when 3.3V MCU clamps voltage and draws excessive clamping current.

The 5V FTDI RX may also have problems detectint 3.3V TX signal from MCU.

Comment: i should connect the FTDI with 3v3 ?

Comment: @walidBmd Yes, that is one option, but it needs to be done properly. Another solution is to level shift between 5V and 3.3V.

Comment: i can't level shift since it's a custom PCB board

Comment: well i will try to level shift with VCCIO and Vout pins , i was reading the application circuit and just found it, Thank you so much sir !

Comment: Cut the VCCIO from the 5V and connect it to 3V3OUT pin (which provide a 50mA 3.3V). From the page 7 of datasheet: "+1.8V to +5.25V supply to the UART Interface and CBUS group pins (1...3, 5, 6, 9...14, 22, 23). In USB bus powered designs connect this pin to 3V3OUT pin to drive out at +3.3V levels, or connect to VCC to drive out at 5V CMOS level".

Comment: i have done that and it's uploading perfectly but it's rebooting once the program finished executing , it keeps rebooting :

abort() was called at PC 0x400d890d on core 0


Backtrace: 0x40083349:0x3ffbe9cc |<-CORRUPTED




ELF file SHA256: e7e23dd0276ce281

Rebooting...
ets Jul 29 2019 12:21:46

rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:2
load:0x3fff0030,len:1184
load:0x40078000,len:13232
load:0x40080400,len:3028
entry 0x400805e4

Comment: i fixed the problem , thank you sir !!